# Unpacking "0xff" vs. "\xff"

Tags: python

I'm trying to read the binary data from a wavefile using the wave library.  The data is read and reported as string literals of the form '\x0f\x06\x0a...' and I would like to convert hexadecimal numbers to integers (you know, in base ten).  The problem I'm having is that these strings aren't really being treating as hex numbers, but sort of like unicode characters.

```
import wave
import struct

path="C:\\directory\\file.wav"

file=wave.open(path,'r')
data=file.readframes(10)

print repr(data)
```

'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

```
int_dat=struct.unpack('10i',data)
```

The error that comes up when I try something like

```
struct.unpack('i','\xff')
```

is that struct.unpack is expecting a string of length 4, and is only receiving a string of length 1.  It's clear to me why that's happening, but is there a format option for unpack that will allow me to unpack '\xff'?

```
struct.unpack('i','0xff')
```

Obviously works fine.  Similarly

```
struct.unpack('i',r'\xff')
```

works.

Alternatively, is there a convenient to convert a string that looks like '\xff\x01\x63...'
to either a raw string (though I'm not sure that makes sense since the "\x" is being treated as an escape character (is that the right term?) and not a character), or to the form '0xff0x010x63'.

Comment: Welcome to SO and +1 for the well-written question.

Comment: What is the exact form of the input?  Does it actually have leading and trailing single quotes?  It would help if you added the exact output from doing `print data`.

Comment: Would also help if you added output from `print repr(data)`.  It seems exceedingly strange that a wave file would contain text rather than raw binary data to begin with.

Comment: Unfortunately that's hard to add.  When I do `print data` ten boxes are displayed (presumably because that's the file begins with a bunch of zeroes and that's what \x00 is interpreted as.

Writing in the interpreter `>>data` yields
`>>'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: Paste in output from `print repr(data)`.  That will produce only printable characters.

Comment: In that case, your file doesn't contain "string literals" at all.  It starts with a bunch of 0 bytes.  Since it **is** a binary file, you first need to change the `'r'` in your `open()` call to `'rb'`.  You're running on Windows, and on Windows you must open binary files in binary mode (trust me on this ;-) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, from the comments it's clear that this is a binary file, not a file of string literals.  That's OK - we **expect** a `.wav` file to be binary data.

Change the `open()` mode to `rb` first.

Then, if you read 10 bytes, you can unpack them via

```
struct.unpack('10b', data)
```

That will return a tuple of 10 integers.  You're almost there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`ord()` will convert bytestring elements into its corresponding value.

```
>>> ord('\x0f')
15
```

Or use an appropriately-sized `struct` conversion.

```
>>> struct.unpack('b', '\x0f')
(15,)
```

Comment: It seems that `struct.unpack('20b',data)` is what I needed.  Thanks!